# Storing the password to a vault in the vault itself?

Tags: password-management

Is there an additional risk associated with storing the master password to a vault inside the vault itself?

I would assume not, since in order to decrypt the vault you must already have that password. But maybe I'm missing something?

And without reuse concerns, anything that can steal the password from the unlocked vault can also just steal the vault itself, so no additional information is being exposed that way.

As to why, besides academic curiosity, I've also noticed that sometimes the web version of the vault does not automatically log me in, even if the native app is unlocked. So adding the vault password would simplify that process.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to? What's the benefit to offset any risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definitely**

You're primary assumption here is that the only way in the vault is with the master password. This is not true. Some other ways:

1. You walk away from your computer with it unlocked and a coworker/housemate sits down
2. You open up the vault and someone sees your master password over your shoulder
3. Your computer is hacked or the session for your vault is stolen (if an online one)

The trouble is that most of these imply temporary access, while if someone finds your master password they can gain permanent access or even lock you out. Imagine a coworker who knows that your password is in your vault and "for fun" waits for you to leave your desk with your computer unlocked. If they know what they are doing it will take 30 seconds to change your master password and kick you out of your own account.

Is that a concern for you? I have no idea! Are these real risks though? Absolutely!

Comment: 2 doesn't apply, since that's actually access to the master password _without_ access to the vault. But the rest of the answer is great. The duration of access and the ability to use the password to change the password is exactly what I was looking for. Arguably 3 also doesn't really preclude stealing the password itself if the computer itself is compromised, but session compromise is a good point.

Comment: @Soumya for #2 I specifically meant if you opened the "secret" that stored your master password while someone was standing over your shoulder. Most password managers let you copy secrets without seeing them, but if you choose to view the secret while someone is standing behind you it will be visible, which isn't the case if you were just typing it in to a password prompt.

Comment: Ah. Yeah that makes more sense. Althought it would be a poor password manager that just dumped all your passwords to the screen whenever you unlocked it... :)